# Is it possible to know when an upsert query has done nothing?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a chain of queries that start with an upsert. I would like the skip all of the following queries if the first query is found to be in conflict. Is there a way for the upsert to return a value that indicates a conflict exists? I am using the Npgsql nugget on c#

Answer (score 0):

Npgsql's [ExecuteNonQuery](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery) returns the number of rows affected, which will be 0 if all inserted rows had a conflict.

Comment: Would there be a way to integrate this if the queries were part of a transaction?

Comment: I see no problem doing that. Write code with an `if` statement.